# How to add custom data to the `info` object using a Winston custom transport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, logging, winston

I'm currently making a custom transport for Winston, and I need to add metadata to the `info` object, like below:

```
{
  message: 'Test',
  level: 'warn',
  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:27:14.420Z',
  event_id: 'test',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',
  [Symbol(message)]: '\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:27:14.420Z : Test\x1B[39m'
}
```

This is what *should* appear when I `console.log(info)` within my code. However, I get a very strange issue of what almost seems to be a "recursive" stack trace. I've shortened it somewhat so it's more understandable.

```
// from `console.log(info)`
  message: 'Test',
  level: 'warn',
  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn'
}
// the warning I made
[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test
// Nothing after here should happen!
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({
  message: 'Test',
  level: 'warn',
  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',
  event_id: 'test',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',
  [Symbol(message)]: '\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\x1B[39m'
})
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:events:502:17)
    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:639:12)
    at CustomTransport.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at CustomTransport.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at errorOrDestroy (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js:98:101)
    at onwriteError (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:424:5)
    at onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:450:11)
    at WritableState.onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:160:5)
{
  error: Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({
    message: 'Test',
    level: 'warn',
    timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',
    event_id: 'test',
    [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',
    [Symbol(message)]: '\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\x1B[39m'
  })
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
      at DerivedLogger.emit (node:events:502:17)
      at DerivedLogger.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:639:12)
      at CustomTransport.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at CustomTransport.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at errorOrDestroy (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js:98:101)
      at onwriteError (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:424:5)
      at onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:450:11)
      at WritableState.onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:160:5) {
    code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR',
    context: {
      message: 'Test',
      level: 'warn',
      timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',
      event_id: 'test',
      [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',
      [Symbol(message)]: '\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\x1B[39m'
    }
  },
  level: 'error',
  message: 'uncaughtException: Unhandled error. ({\n' +
    "  message: 'Test',\n" +
    "  level: 'warn',\n" +
    "  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',\n" +
    "  event_id: 'test',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(message)]: '\\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\\x1B[39m'\n" +
    '})\n' +
    'Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({\n' +
    "  message: 'Test',\n" +
    "  level: 'warn',\n" +
    "  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',\n" +
    "  event_id: 'test',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(message)]: '\\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\\x1B[39m'\n" +
    '})\n' +
    '    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:events:502:17)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:639:12)\n' +
    '    at CustomTransport.emit (node:events:525:35)\n' +
    '    at CustomTransport.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n' +
    '    at errorOrDestroy (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js:98:101)\n' +
    '    at onwriteError (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:424:5)\n' +
    '    at onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:450:11)\n' +
    '    at WritableState.onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:160:5)',
  stack: 'Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({\n' +
    "  message: 'Test',\n" +
    "  level: 'warn',\n" +
    "  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',\n" +
    "  event_id: 'test',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(message)]: '\\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\\x1B[39m'\n" +
    '})\n' +
    '    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:events:502:17)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:639:12)\n' +
    '    at CustomTransport.emit (node:events:525:35)\n' +
    '    at CustomTransport.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n' +
    '    at errorOrDestroy (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js:98:101)\n' +
    '    at onwriteError (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:424:5)\n' +
    '    at onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:450:11)\n' +
    '    at WritableState.onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:160:5)',
  exception: true,
  date: 'Fri Dec 02 2022 12:29:26 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)',
  process: {
    pid: 18296,
    uid: 1000,
    gid: 1000,
    cwd: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot',
    execPath: '/home/ethan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.10.0/bin/node',
    version: 'v18.10.0',
    argv: [
      '/home/ethan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.10.0/bin/node',
      '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/src/index.js',
      'src/index.js'
    ],
    memoryUsage: {
      rss: 91942912,
      heapTotal: 59322368,
      heapUsed: 29791992,
      external: 20277528,
      arrayBuffers: 18684631
    }
  },
  os: { loadavg: [ 0.88, 0.95, 0.82 ], uptime: 4224.99 },
  trace: [
    {
      column: 5,
      file: 'node:internal/errors',
      function: 'new NodeError',
      line: 393,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 17,
      file: 'node:events',
      function: 'DerivedLogger.emit',
      line: 502,
      method: 'emit',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 12,
      file: 'node:domain',
      function: 'DerivedLogger.emit',
      line: 489,
      method: 'emit',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 12,
      file: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js',
      function: 'DerivedLogger.transportEvent',
      line: 639,
      method: 'transportEvent',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 35,
      file: 'node:events',
      function: 'CustomTransport.emit',
      line: 525,
      method: 'emit',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 12,
      file: 'node:domain',
      function: 'CustomTransport.emit',
      line: 489,
      method: 'emit',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 101,
      file: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js',
      function: 'errorOrDestroy',
      line: 98,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 5,
      file: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js',
      function: 'onwriteError',
      line: 424,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 11,
      file: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js',
      function: 'onwrite',
      line: 450,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 5,
      file: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js',
      function: 'WritableState.onwrite',
      line: 160,
      method: 'onwrite',
      native: false
    }
  ],
  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.044Z',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'error'
}
{
  error: Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({
    message: 'Test',
    level: 'warn',
    timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',
    event_id: 'test',
    [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',
    [Symbol(message)]: '\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\x1B[39m'
  })
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
      at DerivedLogger.emit (node:events:502:17)
      at DerivedLogger.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:639:12)
      at CustomTransport.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at CustomTransport.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at errorOrDestroy (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js:98:101)
      at onwriteError (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:424:5)
      at onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:450:11)
      at WritableState.onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:160:5) {
    code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR',
    context: {
      message: 'Test',
      level: 'warn',
      timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',
      event_id: 'test',
      [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',
      [Symbol(message)]: '\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\x1B[39m'
    }
  },
  level: 'error',
  message: 'uncaughtException: Unhandled error. ({\n' +
    "  message: 'Test',\n" +
    "  level: 'warn',\n" +
    "  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',\n" +
    "  event_id: 'test',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(message)]: '\\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\\x1B[39m'\n" +
    '})\n' +
    'Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({\n' +
    "  message: 'Test',\n" +
    "  level: 'warn',\n" +
    "  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',\n" +
    "  event_id: 'test',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(message)]: '\\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\\x1B[39m'\n" +
    '})\n' +
    '    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:events:502:17)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:639:12)\n' +
    '    at CustomTransport.emit (node:events:525:35)\n' +
    '    at CustomTransport.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n' +
    '    at errorOrDestroy (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js:98:101)\n' +
    '    at onwriteError (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:424:5)\n' +
    '    at onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:450:11)\n' +
    '    at WritableState.onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:160:5)',
  stack: 'Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({\n' +
    "  message: 'Test',\n" +
    "  level: 'warn',\n" +
    "  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',\n" +
    "  event_id: 'test',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',\n" +
    "  [Symbol(message)]: '\\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\\x1B[39m'\n" +
    '})\n' +
    '    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:events:502:17)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n' +
    '    at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:639:12)\n' +
    '    at CustomTransport.emit (node:events:525:35)\n' +
    '    at CustomTransport.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n' +
    '    at errorOrDestroy (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js:98:101)\n' +
    '    at onwriteError (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:424:5)\n' +
    '    at onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:450:11)\n' +
    '    at WritableState.onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:160:5)',
  exception: true,
  date: 'Fri Dec 02 2022 12:29:26 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)',
  process: {
    pid: 18296,
    uid: 1000,
    gid: 1000,
    cwd: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot',
    execPath: '/home/ethan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.10.0/bin/node',
    version: 'v18.10.0',
    argv: [
      '/home/ethan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.10.0/bin/node',
      '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/src/index.js',
      'src/index.js'
    ],
    memoryUsage: {
      rss: 91942912,
      heapTotal: 59322368,
      heapUsed: 29791992,
      external: 20277528,
      arrayBuffers: 18684631
    }
  },
  os: { loadavg: [ 0.88, 0.95, 0.82 ], uptime: 4224.99 },
  trace: [
    {
      column: 5,
      file: 'node:internal/errors',
      function: 'new NodeError',
      line: 393,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 17,
      file: 'node:events',
      function: 'DerivedLogger.emit',
      line: 502,
      method: 'emit',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 12,
      file: 'node:domain',
      function: 'DerivedLogger.emit',
      line: 489,
      method: 'emit',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 12,
      file: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js',
      function: 'DerivedLogger.transportEvent',
      line: 639,
      method: 'transportEvent',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 35,
      file: 'node:events',
      function: 'CustomTransport.emit',
      line: 525,
      method: 'emit',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 12,
      file: 'node:domain',
      function: 'CustomTransport.emit',
      line: 489,
      method: 'emit',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 101,
      file: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js',
      function: 'errorOrDestroy',
      line: 98,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 5,
      file: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js',
      function: 'onwriteError',
      line: 424,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 11,
      file: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js',
      function: 'onwrite',
      line: 450,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 5,
      file: '/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js',
      function: 'WritableState.onwrite',
      line: 160,
      method: 'onwrite',
      native: false
    }
  ],
  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.044Z',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'error',
  [Symbol(message)]: '\x1B[31m[error] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.044Z: uncaughtException: Unhandled error. ({\x1B[39m\n' +
    "\x1B[31m  message: 'Test',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  level: 'warn',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  event_id: 'test',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  [Symbol(message)]: '\\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\\x1B[39m'\x1B[39m\n" +
    '\x1B[31m})\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31mError [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({\x1B[39m\n' +
    "\x1B[31m  message: 'Test',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  level: 'warn',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  event_id: 'test',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  [Symbol(message)]: '\\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\\x1B[39m'\x1B[39m\n" +
    '\x1B[31m})\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:events:502:17)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:domain:489:12)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:639:12)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at CustomTransport.emit (node:events:525:35)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at CustomTransport.emit (node:domain:489:12)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at errorOrDestroy (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js:98:101)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at onwriteError (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:424:5)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:450:11)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at WritableState.onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:160:5)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31mError [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({\x1B[39m\n' +
    "\x1B[31m  message: 'Test',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  level: 'warn',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  timestamp: '2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  event_id: 'test',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  [Symbol(level)]: 'warn',\x1B[39m\n" +
    "\x1B[31m  [Symbol(message)]: '\\x1B[33m[warn] 2022-12-02T17:29:26.007Z : Test\\x1B[39m'\x1B[39m\n" +
    '\x1B[31m})\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:events:502:17)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at DerivedLogger.emit (node:domain:489:12)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:639:12)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at CustomTransport.emit (node:events:525:35)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at CustomTransport.emit (node:domain:489:12)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at errorOrDestroy (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js:98:101)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at onwriteError (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:424:5)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:450:11)\x1B[39m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m    at WritableState.onwrite (/home/ethan/Documents/StatusPlusDiscordBot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/e.js:160:5)\x1B[39m'
}
```

Unfortunately, there is a lack of Winston-Transport documentation, so I had to make some guesses on how to add custom information in the transport.

My class is as below:

```js
class CustomTransport extends Transport {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-constructor
  constructor(opts) {
    super(opts);
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line class-methods-use-this
  log(info, callback) {
    info.event_id = 'test'

    // this.emit('logged', info);
    webhook(info);

    callback(info);
  }
}
```

Of course, this causes the issue. Removing `info` from callback also fixes the issue, but then custom info is not added to the `info` object used in the main library.

How should I go about fixing this? Am I doing anything else wrong?

Thanks!

#### EDIT1

After making the changes described below, I still do not see any extra info logged to the console (none of the extra information I included at least) but the "recursive" Stack Trace is gone.

Here's my entire code for logging in case it helps:

```js
// Full-Scale Logging stack for Status+ - @FxllenCode
// This may be open source some time in the future :D
// This is a modified version of the original logger.js file
// It uses Sentry.io for a full-scale logging stack, but also Winston for local logging, and a webhook for a remote logging stack

const winston = require('winston');
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node')
const Tracing = require('@sentry/tracing');
const Transport = require('winston-transport');
const webhook = require('./hook.js')

// Using LogForm standard, create a nice logging format
const format = winston.format.combine(
  winston.format.timestamp(),
  winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
  winston.format.printf((info) => {
    console.log(info)
    if (info.stack) {
      return winston.format.colorize().colorize(info.level, `[${info.level}] ${info.timestamp}: ${info.message}\n${info.stack}`);
    }
    return winston.format.colorize().colorize(info.level, `[${info.level}] ${info.timestamp} : ${info.message}`);
  }),
);

class CustomTransport extends Transport {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-constructor
  constructor(opts) {
    super(opts);
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line class-methods-use-this
  log(info, callback) {
    info.event_id = 'test'
    info.custom_data = { key1: 'value1' }
    webhook(info);

    callback(null, info);
  }
}

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info',
  transports: [
    new CustomTransport(),
    new winston.transports.Console(),

  ],
  format,

});

module.exports = logger;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the lack of documentation, however, after looking here:

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#adding-custom-transports

It seems like the log function in a custom transport should accept two parameters: `info` and `callback`. The `info` parameter is an object containing the log message and related metadata. The `callback` parameter is a function that should be called with either an error object or null as the first argument, and the info object with any additional data as the second argument. This should allow custom transports to add additional data to the info object before passing it back to the main library.

Now looking at your code:

```
class CustomTransport extends Transport {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-constructor
  constructor(opts) {
    super(opts);
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line class-methods-use-this
  log(info, callback) {
    info.event_id = 'test'

    // this.emit('logged', info);
    webhook(info);

    callback(info);
  }
}
```

If you want to add custom info to the info object, then you need to call `callback(null, info);` instead of `callback(info)`. This should pass the info object with the custom info to the main library, and it will be available in the info object.

**EDIT:**

This code below should create a custom transport for Winston, which is a logging library.

The log() method is overridden to add a custom field, 'event_id', with the value 'test' as well as a custom_data field with the specified values to the info object.

This info object is then passed to the webhook method and the callback function is called with the updated info object.

Finally, the custom transport is added to the Winston logger instance, which can be used to log messages.

The addition of the `custom_data` field is so we can use it to add additional data that is specific to the application, or in this case, for testing.

For example, if you are logging events related to an online store, you could add information about the customer, their order, or any other data related to the event. This will allow for more detailed logging and analysis of the events that are occurring in the application.

```
// Create a custom transport for Winston
class CustomTransport extends Transport {
  constructor(opts) { 
    super(opts); 
  }

  log(info, callback) { // Override the log() method
    info.event_id = 'test' // Add the event_id field with the value 'test' to the info object
    info.custom_data = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } // Add a custom_data field with the specified values to the info object for further analysis

    webhook(info); // Call the webhook method with the updated info object
    callback(null, info); // Call the callback function with the updated info object
  }
}

// Use the custom transport in your Winston logger
const logger = createLogger({
  transports: [new CustomTransport()] // Add the custom transport to the Winston logger instance
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, there is no "recursive" stack trace so you are onto something, but sadly the `info` option didn't include `test` for `event_id` - in fact, there was nothing there at all.

Comment: Interesting. See my edit and see if you get a different result.

Comment: I've taken the steps you suggested but it still didn't work - updated my post with more information. Did it work for you on your end?

Comment: I'm actually not running the code myself, just looking at the docs to see how we can test. Is there any chance you can include more info with what is going on in hook.js?

Comment: FWIW hook.js is empty and does not do anything yet, so it shouldn't be causing any issues.

Comment: Interesting, I believe the webhook function is necessary for the logger to send messages to the Sentry service (if that is what you're trying to do).

Comment: Correct, but in this case I haven't implemented that yet - I am just trying to keep `event_id` as `test` for the time being, which I can't do yet. :)